# Restar entre dos consultas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo dos consultas dentro de `SQL SERVER` las cuales me devuelven un numero, quiero restar los resultados de ambas querys para obtener un total.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(cantidad AS INT)) from C_APP_REGISTROS WHERE id_insumo = 460;
```

Esta consulta en este momento me devuelve `7`.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(cantidad AS INT)) FROM (
    select r.cantidad as cantidad from  C_APP_REGISTROS a 
    inner join C_APP_RETIROS r on r.id_registro = a.IDREG 
    INNER JOIN C_APP_INSUMOS i on a.id_insumo = i.IDINS WHERE id_insumo = 460 
    ) SRC
```

La siguiente me devuleve el valor `12`.

Por lo tanto quiero restar entre ambas consultas y obtener el resultado  `-5`

Para esto e intentado algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT SUM(CAST(cantidad AS INT)) from C_APP_REGISTROS WHERE id_insumo = 460) 
    -
    (SELECT SUM(CAST(cantidad AS INT)) FROM (
    select r.cantidad as cantidad from  C_APP_REGISTROS a 
    inner join C_APP_RETIROS r on r.id_registro = a.IDREG 
    INNER JOIN C_APP_INSUMOS i on a.id_insumo = i.IDINS WHERE id_insumo = 460 
    ) SRC)
    )
```

Existe manera de llegar al resultado? o es mejor efectuar esto desde el servidor?

Comment: Qué respuesta obtienes?

Comment: La sentencia  final no funciona, entrega el siguiente error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ')'.

Comment: Tal vez ese sea tu problema... elimina el punto y coma después de    id_insumo = 460;

Comment: me sigue dando error en la operacion "-"

Answer (score 0):

Para automatizarlo, podrías conseguirlo creando un procedimiento almacenado:

```
DELIMITER $$
Create procedure usp_obtener_resta()
BEGIN
SET @valor_1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TB_VOTANTES); -- Reemplaza con su primera consulta
SET @valor_2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TB_LOCALIDAD); -- Reemplaza con su segunda consulta
-- En mi caso:
-- @valor_1 = 15
-- @valor_2 = 5
 SELECT (@valor_1 - @valor_2) as RESULTADO
 FROM TB_VOTANTES LIMIT 1;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Luego mandamos a ejecutar: `Call usp_obtener_resta(); -- Resultado: 5`

Lo puede **personalizar mandando los id como parámetro en el procedimiento**, si desea obtener resultados con la clausula "*WHERE*".

Comment: Hola Moisés. La pregunta tiene el tag de sql server. Me parece tu respuesta lleva sintaxis de mysql

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Necesito la consulta para ejecutarla luego mediante Node.js, pero si hago esto tal vez seria mejor realizar ambas consultas y almacenarlas dentro de variables en el servidor para luego restar ambas. Mi idea era obtener un resultado inmediato mediante una qry.

Comment: Hola Arriel, tienes razón, solo que vi sintaxis de mysql y decidí adjuntar en base a ello.

Comment: Entiendo, Matías. Podrías tal vez usar una función que retorne dicho valor, aunque sería algo similar con lo del procedimiento almacenado.